# Print 'error' if min function has no argument

Tags: python, error-handling, min

I´m wrting a code to determine the next higher number that can be built with the same digits the original given number obtains.

I found some code:

```
def findnext(ii): 
    return min(v for v in (int("".join(x)) for x in itertools.permutations(str(ii))) if v>ii)
```

The function is working properly but what if my min fuction has an error because no value is passed. For instance, this happens when you insert ii= 513 as there cant be a higher number formed. Is there a way to avoid the error and instead return for example a string???

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Incorrect use _should_ raise an exception. Making someone who uses your function check if the return value is a string is making them do extra work that using Python the way it's designed (which is to say, with exceptions) will avoid.

Comment: Is there a way to cover my problem with try and except?? @Charles Duffy